# How to authenticate 2 different mvc application using identity server 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have Two mvc application.So I want when user log into my first mvc application that user get login for the second application too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation you are trying to achieve requires single sign on to be integrated. There is a nice article available for this [here](http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc)